# How to avoid SEGMENTATION ERROR for the code below?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, maps, dynamic-programming

I'm getting **Segmentation error** for the code below. This is a solution to [the SPOJ problem "Coins"](http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/).

I went through [How to avoid SIGSEGV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768532/how-to-avoid-sigsegv) and I made sure not to use uninitialized pointers, not to access out of memory etc (given *n ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>*).

I know that an array `a[1000000000]` would lead to stack overflow, so I used `std::map`. Will a `std::map` ever lead to a stack overflow? What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<unsigned long long int, unsigned long long int> a;

unsigned long long int dp(unsigned long long int n)
{   
   if (a.find(n) == a.end())
      a[n] = dp(n/2) + dp(n/3) + dp(n/4);

   return a[n];
}

int main()
{
    for (unsigned long long int i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
        if (i == 12 || i == 24)
           a[i] = i + 1;
    }

    unsigned long long int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        printf("%llu\n", dp(n));
        cin >> n;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Michelle sure it is.  Look at the for loop at the beginning of `main()`

Comment: @Michelle : I made it global

Comment: If you are going to have 10^9 long long's then that is going to take up more than 7GB of memory.  How much memory do you have?

Comment: [`while(!feof(stdin))`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Your indentation is weird

Comment: Why do you need to store values in a container?  You can input one line, calculate the result, then read in the next line.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The result of one line depends on the result of a previous line. Read the definition of `dp`: it's recursive.

Comment: Provide sample input, please. Ideally abstract away the `cin` calls entirely, taking data from a `stringstream` instead. Then this'll be a good question & I'll be able to just reproduce this and troubleshoot it within seconds.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks for formatting my question...

Comment: sample test cases Input:
12
1
24
10000
1000000000
Output:
13
1
25
16609
4186477065

Comment: @rsd_unleashed: Next time do it yourself please.

Comment: @rsd_unleashed: That output works fine, on at least one machine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd7dea2ed4a35420

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : That's the main problem....Even Ideone accepted the code...However spoj compiler says SIGSEGV.....  http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/

Comment: @NathanOliver:Not actually,spoj compiler shows memory usage of 11M.However the limit is 1500M

Comment: _"Each testcase is a single line" "For each test case output a single line"_ You got the assignment wrong anyway :P

Comment: Three things: If you use a global array there will be no problems with stack overflow. The maximum result, 4186477065, fits in 32 bits. You don't need to store all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You get SIGSEGV on `dp(0)` call. It causes an infinite recursion.**

By the way, your solution is wrong, for example the answer for 24 is not 25. Try to avoid magic constants, it is just enough to set `a[0] = 0` and make a more accurate `dp` function:

```cpp
uint32_t dp(uint32_t n) {
    if (a.find(n) == a.end())
        a[n] = max(n, dp(n / 2) + dp(n / 3) + dp(n / 4));

    return a[n];
}
```

As can be seen above, 32-bit type is enough to store any possible answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton.....AC..... Want to upvote your ans....But new to stackoverflow...Don't have enough reputation :)